# Finite parallel impedance network general solution

Tags: passive-networks, transmission-line

Does anyone know if a finite number of parallel-series impedance has a general solution?

I am trying to model a network flow problem that can be described in electrical terms and represented as a finite discrete transmission line with arbitrary impedance.

While it is not difficult to write the equations down for a small number of terms, I'm curious if there are some general solutions or insights into the problem.

It looks like

```
----Z1---+----Z3---+----Z5---+---...---+
         |         |         |         |
         Z2        Z4        Z6        ZN
         |         |         |         |
---------+---------+---------+---...---+
```

All the Z's are, in general, different.

I'll need to know the "current" and/or "voltage" at every branch. In this case the bottom is grounded.

What would be cool is to be able to know the voltage and/or current in terms of i, the ith position (the top +).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Modified Nodal Analysis](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/mna/MNA2.html) method for solving the nodal voltages, and then back-compute the branch currents.

The beauty of this technique is that it generalizes very well to any well defined netlist and is quite easy to program. This technique can give either an analytical or a numerical solution, depending on your solver, and can be used to solve DC, steady state AC, or full transient problems.

The first link gives good resources on how to solve linear DC and steady-state AC circuits, and if you want to solve linear transient problems I have a [blog post](http://helloworld922.blogspot.com/2013/04/transmission-line-simulation.html) about how to approximate the inductors and capacitors to solve a transient problem.

edit:

In response to the OP's comments,

Matrix inverses can be solved analytically, though the degree of difficulty increases drastically for larger matrices (note: difficulty = time, just follow Gaussian elimination).

Some methods for finding matrix inverses **analytically**:

1. [Gaussian Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)
2. [LU Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition)
3. [QR Factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition)

... take your pick. The reason I suggested using a computer (even if the computer is solving your system analytically for you) is because for any appreciable size matrix it will take you a very long time to solve by hand.

This is the exact solution if you have a discrete/finite number of nodes, and there's no way around this linear algebra problem.

Maxwell's equations can have a "simple" looking solution because they don't apply to a discrete/finite domain: they rely on continuous functions and thus all the tools of calculus are available.

If you can make the approximation that the number of nodes tends towards infinity and don't care for the discrete nature of your network, you can simulate your transmission line using the [Telegrapher's Equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations). These will have solutions of a similar form to Maxwell's equations. For example, the solution to a lossless transmission line is:
$$
V(x, t) = f_1(x-u t) + f_2(x+u t)
$$
$$
I(x, t) = \frac{f_1(x-u t)}{Z_0} + \frac{f_2(x+u t)}{Z_0}
$$
A.k.a. the homogeneous wave equation solution.

A lossy transmission line can be described as a non-homogeneous wave equation, who's solution can be found by applying [Green's Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) to find the particular solution and adding on the homogeneous solution, or by only using Green's Function (details omitted).

**Edit 2:**

One of the limitations with using Nodal Analysis is you need to fully specify the problem, i.e. specify the entire network and boundary conditions. You have not specified what's connected to the input/output of your "transmission" line, which is why I don't know what your full network will look like and consequently can't offer any advice other than the "general" linear algebra techniques.

In my blog post, I noticed that even though my entire network results in a non-[tri-diagonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix), I could easily reduce it into one by not solving for IS at the same time as all the nodal voltages, and re-arranging the matrix form. [Thomas's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm) provides a very efficient method for expressing the solution to a tri-diagonal system.

Comment: While this is on the right track I was hoping that a direct closed form solution existed. Essentially the inversion of your matrix. I'm not 100% sure the results are directly applicable(just redefining terms) but it's a start. ATM I'm not looking for an algorithmic solution. (I'm not even sure if the math is the exact same between the two different problems).

Comment: If you look further into the first link, the author presents SCAM, which uses Matlab to analytically solve a given network by framing it as a linear algebra problem. Linear systems are very well studied and there are many algorithms for solving them. If your question is on methods for solving the system Ax=b using a computer, you might get better results asking on stackoverflow or the comp.sci stack exchange.

Comment: No, I am looking for a mathematical expression of the solution. For example, one can "solve" maxwell's equations because of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations. It is a "closed form" analytical solution of the pde's. Just "plug and play".  `Ax=b` has the solution `x = A^(-1)*b`. I am looking for a similar thing. Basically I would like to know what the inverted matrices that you have are.  There is probably a closed form expression for it. (Basically it probably involves inverting it by hand and seeing the pattern)

Comment: I don't want just an expression of the problem that requires me to use a computer to solve the problem indirectly. E.g., I could use numerical integration to solve maxwell's equations or I could use jefimenko's equations which require numerical integration. The difference is one is a direct solution and one is not. (Jefimenk's does not involve circular expressions and is directly expressed in known quantities... of course it is actually harder to solve numerically but that's besides the point)

Comment: I've updated my answer: basically a discrete network requires you solve a system `Ax=b`. Maxwell's equations have a nice form because they rely on a continuum: the non-discrete nature allows the tools of calculus to be applied, and a concise solution can be found.

Comment: No, my number is few. My point was not about the discrete vs continuous math, that is irrelevant, but given something like Ax = b I want x = A^(-1)b. This tells me x directly and does not require me to solve for it(finding the inverse). The matrices on your website are not inverted, hence not helpful to me directly. If you can invert them(plug them in to maple should do the trick) then they would be helpful to me. The form they have when not inverted, while simple, does not allow me to deduce much about "x".

Comment: I was imply trying to use maxwell's equations as an analogy. The equations do not directly offer much insight into certain solutions because they are not a function of independent variables. They are circularly dependent functions. Jefimenko's equations, OTOH, are expressed in terms of simple well known quantities and are not circular. Hence, if you know the density and the current you know E and H. (sure those integrals are a biatch to solve but that isn't the point)

Comment: With Maxwell's equations, if you know the density and current you have to go through several steps to find E and H. (there are 4 equations that use the dependent variables as independent variables in some)

Comment: It is quite simple. It is analogous to any expression that is a "direct" solution(requires minimal amount of work). The quadratic formula is a direct solution to a 2nd order polynomial... it requires just plugging in values and simplifying to get the solution. No "tricks" or complicated things. (they were already done to get the equation in the first place by completing the square... but all you have to know is arithmetic to use it)

Comment: I don't want to have to invert your matrix because it is too difficult... I was hoping someone has done it before. I could plug it into maple and get a result but it would be for fixed in... Also, my problem is slightly different so might end up being more work.

Comment: If your complete network is different, you have a different linear system to solve. You can't solve just part of the system, in general it needs to be solved "all at once". I added a minor addendum about the method I used to solve my particular system. If you're not able to manipulate your system into one like I had, you'll have to solve the system yourself. Try to identify patterns in your matrix or if your matrix can be manipulated into a special form. Yes, it's a huge pain to do but that's the only advice I can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it is possible based on "partial fraction" developments (introduced by FOSTER):
Please note that for convenience you should replace all even elements by the corresponding conductances (Z2>>>Y2, Z4>>>Y4, ...).

Then, we have

Z= Z1 + 1/D1

D1=Y2 + 1/D2

D2=Z3 + 1/D3

D3=Y4 + 1/D4

....

Comment: Yeah, these equations are basically what comes out of the solution when you write down the total impedance. Is Dn used in any simple way to calculate the voltages and currents at the upper nodes?